# text size going out from its background. How to stop?

Tags: html, angular, sass

I have uploaded image for the reference. Here text of `<p>` tag taking space above its background size. I tried zeroing few properties but no luck. [image]

```
.p1 {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: #212529 !important;
  font-size: 2.5rem !important;
  line-height: 1 !important;
  display: block !important;
    margin-block-start: 0 !important;
    margin-block-end: 0 !important;
    margin-inline-start: 0 !important;
    margin-inline-end: 0 !important;
    text-size-adjust: auto !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

I tried separately, adding the `<p>` tag with new html file and adding size and background colour, I did not find any issue there. In my project I am getting the problem. Please suggest me how this occurs so that I will check in my project code where it is went wrong and correct that.

Comment: its not a good practice to use  so many `!important` in CSS

Comment: I was testing that if any property is overruling my custom one. Adding !important did not work though.

Comment: `line-height:1rem` (you need add the unit to line-height). You can also `overflow:hidden` to you "text-div" class

Comment: overflow:hidden in parent is chopping the upper part of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your font-size and line height. Check if font-size and line-height are smaller than the parent div.

Comment: I made parent div as flex and resizes according to font size. I just added background color to <p> tag and noticed it is not aligned. background colour is not for parent div but to the same <p> tag.

Comment: Can you check the line-height property by using some constant values in px.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).